# need same font size for upper and lower case

Tags: css, xforms

Html text box should have same font size for both upper and lower case chars.

For example, i have a textbox length of 5 using below css class="field-width-5"

```
.field-width-5 { width:5px }


<td class="field-width-5">
      <xforms:input bind="alternate-address-1-postal-code" xxforms:maxlength="5" id="alternate-address-1-postal-code-id"/>
</td>
```

When i enter upper case words such as QWDO, it occupies more space and it exceeds the width of 5px. Is there any font can be applied to over come this issue.

Comment: I think 5px for a post code field is a bit small, or do you use a very tiny font size?

Comment: He must be using [Dotsies](http://dotsies.org/). :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a fixed-width font like `Courier New` on Windows. Generically this is the `monospace` font family in CSS (works on every OS.)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a monospace font like Courier?

Answer (score 0):

It has the same font size. The dimensions (height and width) of letters have no simple relationship with the font size; they are up to the font designer.

For an input field for five characters, use the HTML attribute `size=5`. It’s the safest way—the field may be somewhat wider than needed, but that’s a smaller problem than making it too narrow. Setting e.g. `width: 3em` in CSS is a reasonable alternative but less safe. Using `width: 5ch` might seem to be more logical, but it isn’t; first, the `ch` unit is not widely supported; second, it is by definition the width of the digit `0`, and many uppercase letters can be wider.