# Does a pure CSS font-size-adjust workaround exist?

Tags: css

I want a smaller font-size differential (between lower and uppercase letters) than that effected by `font-variant:small-caps;`. `font-size-adjust` would seem perfect but it doesn't work. `font-variant:petite-caps;` doesn't noticeably change things.

Does anyone have a pure CSS solution to the problem? I haven't really seen discussion of `font-size-adjust` or this particular issue (perhaps because it doesn't work).

I'm after two different font-sizes: One for upper case and another for lower case letters.

Any help appreciated.

```css
#test{
font-variant:small-caps;
font-size:20px;
font-size-adjust:0.25;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>Test</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: currently [only Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#search=font-size-adjust) supports this CSS rule

Comment: Have own font that has bigger lowercase letters (bigger glyphs)

Comment: @Optimus the question is clear as is. There's no need for additional code

Comment: Thanks all. Sounds like the solution I'm after doesn't exist.

Comment: @scon on the contray, depending on why you want to adjust the font size you can set a new font size relative to screen size, for example, and force the font to be upper or lower case, as required, via CSS .

Comment: @Martin I'm after two different font-sizes: One for upper and another for lower case letters. Are you saying that's possible? If so, would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: You may need a fixed width font such as [on this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828734/need-same-font-size-for-upper-and-lower-case)?

Comment: its not possible as far as i know with pure css, closest thing is selecting all upper_case chars with js and wrap them in a span element, then style that

Comment: Thanks Warden330. That's the impression I'm getting. @Martin - not clear to me how a fixed-width font helps.

Comment: @scon if the font is a monospaced or fixed width font you can scale the whole font rather than just upper or lower case glyphs, because they'll all be the same size, that can be easily done with CSS. But otherwise it seems there's not a lot of options without getting ultra fiddly and breaking words up with `<span>` tags and setting CSS for these....

Comment: Yes, thanks - that was my read.